# Java - unable to change data type from an import file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to convert the import file String data type to Double and do the calculations, but some errors found. Any mistakes when making an assumption?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Q4
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, NumberFormatException
    {
        File file = new File("SalesData.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);

        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String weekly_Sale = inputFile.nextLine();
            String sale = weekly_Sale;
            String list = sale;
            Double value = Double.parseDouble(list);
            Double[]data = value.split(",");
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

The file SalesData.txt contains the dollar amount of sales that a retail store made each day for a number of weeks. Each line in the file contains seven numbers, which are the daily sales for one week. The numbers are separated by a comma. The following is an example from the file:

2541.36,2965.88,1965.32,1845.23,7021.11,9652.74,1469.36

Write a program that opens the file and processes its contents. The program should display the following:

•   The total sales for each week
•   The average daily sales for each week
•   The total sales for all the weeks
•   The average weekly sales
•   The week number that had the highest amount of sales
•   The week number that had the lowest amount of sales

Comment: what is "import file" ?

Comment: Please post the errors that you're getting.

Comment: `Double` doesn't have a `split` method and you can't parse to double a String like `2541.36,2965.88,1965.32...`

Comment: Sorry I am the beginner, I mean read the text file

Comment: Error mag: Q4.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
   Double[]data = value.split(",");
                       ^
  symbol:   method split(String)
  location: variable value of type Double

Comment: so I have to use array list? @JuanCarlosMendoza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Double value = Double.parseDouble(list);
    Double[]data = value.split(",");
```

The order of your operations is incorrect. At first you need to split the line into individual string values and then parse them to double.

Try something like this

```
    String[] data = value.split(",");
    for (String item : data) {
         Double result = Double.parseDouble(item)
         // Do Stuff

    }
```

Comment: I am trying to change the code as below, but still have error msg:        while(inputFile.hasNext()){
   String weekly_Sale = inputFile.nextLine();
   String sale = weekly_Sale;
 
   String[]list = sale.split(",");
   Double data = Double.parseDouble(list);
   
   System.out.println(data);
  }

Comment: And you need to iterate over the array. Double data = Double.parseDouble(list) will not work if list is an array.

Comment: I am doing the same thing as you suggested, and add a syntax of- System.out.println(result). May I know if the 'result' can be print on screen?  error: cannot find symbol

Answer (score 2):

Various things to point out:

- As I commented before, `Double` doesn't have a split method and you can't directly parse to double a String like `2541.36,2965.88,1965.32...`
- It's better to use [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) than [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read a file because is
  [a bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41681758/7694740)
- You can use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to automatically close the io resources.
- Your code can be shortened like this:

  ```
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SalesData.txt"))){

      String currentLine;

      // read each line until the end of the file
      while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
          // split each token to a double-parseable string value, then parse it to a double and finally 
          // collect those values into an array of doubles
          double[] data = Arrays.stream(currentLine.split(",")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
      }
  } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

For this I'm using [Java 8 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
String inputFile = new Scanner(new File("SalesData.txt"))
        .useDelimiter("\\A").next();

String[] s = inputFile.split(",");
double[] dValue = new double[s.length];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    dValue[i] = Double.parseDouble(s[i]);
}
for (double d : dValue) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```